# Editing a DataInputStream save format

Tags: java

So, basically I've been writing a game and the saving uses the DataInputStream and DataOutputStream however, if I edit the values in which I want saved. (Say my game has an update and a new skill is added, and I want to save it) this causes errors upon trying to load the file.

The error I usually keep seeing is this

```
[5/10/14 2:29 AM]: java.io.EOFException
```

Is there any way around this, so I don't have to worry about corrupting everybodies save-data on the multiplayer server every-time that I want to issue an update? I could always go back to BufferedReader and BufferedWriters, but that was horribly messy.

There's got to be a way to just tack more writeInt / readInts on and keep going.

For those who missed the question.

> How can I successfully edit the variables saved and loaded througha  DataInput/Output stream without corrupting the older saved-files. This is being used for a multiplayer server, so anytime that I wish to update information in the users save-file I would add more variables to be saved into the file; However because this data isn't in the old saves, when it tries to load it will look for the newer variables, won't be able to find it and thus creates an error.

Example code(Saving):

```
            FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(file);
        DataOutputStream o = new DataOutputStream(fileOutputStream);
        o.writeUTF(playerName);
        o.writeUTF(playerPass);
        o.writeInt(playerHealth);
        o.close();
        fileOutputStream.close();
```

Example Code (Loading)

```
            FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
        DataInputStream l = new DataInputStream(fileInputStream);
        playerName = l.readUTF();
        String password = l.readUTF();
        if (!password.equals(pw)) {
            return 3;
        }
        playerPass = password;
        playerHealth = l.readInt();
        l.close();
        fileInputStream.close();
```

Now lets say I wanted to save the int playermana to the save file in an update.

All of the save-files that don't have playermana wont be able to load due to not having the data there already; How can I work around this.

Comment: Saved how? Edited how? Code? Question?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use a database. Why not use a database that already exists rather than writing one from scratch?

Comment: Code/Question re-written for better understanding.

Comment: @Joni - I don't want to use SQL at the moment, if that is what you mean by a "database". I just want to use a standard binary format read/write saving.

Comment: If you have something against SQL you don't have to use it. There are many different kinds of databases.

Comment: I don't have anything against SQL. I love it. However I'm honestly just not sure about how to structure my tables for the game at the moment so I'm trying to avoid it while studying.

Comment: `writeUTF()` isnt' exactly a 'standard binary format'. It is unique to Java and to `DataOutput` and `DataInput`. You'll never be able to edit it. Use another format.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to be able to change the format and still be able to read old formats, you need a self describing data format.  Conceptually, you can look at JSon, but you want a binary equivalent (I assume)

In a binary form you can add details such as the number of entries (in case this changes), the number of fields for each entry (in case this changes), the format of elements in an entry e.g. String, double, int, (in case the types change) and possibly you can add a name for each element so the order of fields can change.

There is many ways to break up this problem depending on your requirements.  The more redundancy you put in, the more flexibility you have to cope with possible changes.

Answer (score 0):

There are basically two approaches to making extensible file formats: include a version number in the file, or add an identifier for each field before writing the field. Both ways allow the code that reads the file to know what's actually stored in the file, so it won't try to read fields that are not there.

Since you're writing a multiplayer game you may have another problem too: reading files that have been written only partially. This is not hard to fix, but the effort is probably better invested in migrating to a database engine that has solved these problems already.